# Bengali conjuncts not rendering in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, fonts

```
ggplot(data=NULL,aes(x=1,y=1))+
  geom_text(size=10,label="ক্ত", family="Kohinoor Bangla")
```

On my machine, the Bengali conjunct cluster "ক্ত" is rendered as its constituents plus a virana:

[image: Improper conjunct rendering]

I have tried several different fonts to no avail. Is there a trick to making conjuncts render correctly?

EDIT:

Explicitly using the unicode still doesn't not render correctly:

This renders correctly for me:

```
print(stringi::stri_enc_toutf8("\u0995\u09cd\u09a4"))
```

[image]

This still gives me the exact same result as before

```
ggplot(data=NULL,aes(x=1,y=1))+
  geom_text(size=10,label="\u0995\u09cd\u09a4", family="Kohinoor Bangla")
```

Why is there a difference between the console output and ggplot output?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the Bengali language, but if you would look up the unicode characters for the text that you want to render, you could simply use those in `geom_text()`

```
# According to unicode code chart, these are some Bengali characters
# U+099x4
# U+09Ex3
ggplot(data=NULL,aes(x=1,y=1))+
  # Substitute 'U+' by '\u', leave the 'x' out
  geom_text(size = 10, label = "\u0994\u09E3")
```

[image]

Substitute the unicode characters as you see fit.
Hope that helped!

EDIT: I tried your last piece of code, which gave me a warning about the font not being installed. So I ran it without the `family = "Kohinoor Bangla"`:

```
ggplot(data=NULL,aes(x=1,y=1))+
  geom_text(size=10,label="\u0995\u09cd\u09a4")
```

Which gave me the following output:

[image]

From a visual comparison with the character that you posted, it looks quite similar. Next, I ran the same piece of code on my work computer, which gave me the following output:

[image]

The difference between work and home, is that work runs on a linux, while home runs on windows, work has R 3.4.4, home has R 3.5.3. Both are in RStudio, both are ggplot 3.2.0. I can't update R on work because of backwards compatibility issues, to check wether the version of R might be the problem. However, you could check wether your version of R is older than 3.5.3 and see if updating relieves the problem. Otherwise, I would guess it is a platform issue.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work; I edited my response to include a unicode character version of my code.

Comment: I ran your unicode characters, got two different results on two versions of R (but also two platforms), see edit.